# gcc deep/double/nested casting

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

First is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef wchar_t* BSTR;

wchar_t hello[] = L"Hello";

class _bstr_t {
public:
    operator const wchar_t*() const throw() { return hello; }
    operator wchar_t*() const throw() { return hello; }
};

class container {
public:
    operator _bstr_t() { return _bstr_t(); }
};

int main()
{
    // This gives error (with gcc 4.5.2 at least):
    // test.cpp:20:27: error: cannot convert "container" to "wchar_t*" in initialization
    wchar_t *str = container();
    printf("%S\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that `container()` can be casted to `_bstr_t` and then to `wchar_t*`, but, gcc does not.

The problem can be solved using manual cast:

```
wchar_t *str = (_bstr_t)container();
```

But what I need is to **avoid** manual cast, I would like gcc to figure this out automatically.

Why I need this is because the returned container type objects will be used in calls like

```
void Func(wchar_t* str);
Func(myObject->Container);
```

where I don't want to do manual casting.

I verified Visual Studio and it does not seem to support such scenario, too. Too bad, but I would be glad if someone can provide a workaround, even if for this specific case.

UPDATE: for those who suggests operator wchar_t* on the container, **that** was the problem in first place. This will either leak or crash when destroyed before Func() has a chance to accept the pointer.

Comment: In the future, consider adding a short description of the problem **before** the code.

Comment: I see no crash when I add `operator wchar_t*()`

Comment: Sure because in the example it is a global data. In the real world _bstr_t manages its data and will destroy it just before container::operator wchar_t* will return. But chances your code won't even notice this and will crash at some point after that.

Comment: I am sure I wouldn't notice, because I wouldn't use raw pointers. I would use wstring, or better yet, I would add a method that returns it, instead of using the conversion operator.

Comment: Yes, right, but _they_ did not do it this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing implicit conversions, there's at most *one* user-defined conversion that can happen. MSVC behaviour is not standard compliant in this matter.

C++11 (12.3 Conversions):

> At most one user-deﬁned conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

For the implicit conversion to work, `container` has to convert directly to `wchar_t*`.

Comment: +1 FYI, if extensions are disabled in MSVC the compiler complains.

Comment: Well, I can give you +1 at least because now I know the place in C++ specs and how it's called.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the class container has no `operator wchar_t*()`. The only solution is to add it to the container class :

```
#include <iostream>

typedef wchar_t* BSTR;

wchar_t hello[] = L"Hello";


class container {
public:
    operator const wchar_t*() const throw() { return hello; }
    operator wchar_t*() const throw() { return hello; }
};

int main()
{
    // This gives error (with gcc 4.5.2 at least):
    // test.cpp:20:27: ошибка: cannot convert «container» to «wchar_t*» in initialization
    wchar_t *str = container();
    std::wcout<<str<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have already explained why this does not work. What I need is a solution to do (wchar_t*)container().

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a converter from `wchar_t *` to `container` that is why you get the error

```
class container {
public:
  operator wchar_t*() { return _bstr_t(); }
};
```